# MYSQL merge columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL and do a select:

```
SELECT LTRIM(Firstname + ' ' Lastname) AS Fullname FROM Persons
```

My result is 0 for every result.

Even if i remove the LTRIM, Using CONCAT is giving the same problem.

Comment: What is your question? Why is this a problem? Does Persons actually contain any records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are arithmetically adding the string values together; unless you have "1ohn 5mith" in the db, this will always be 0.

Does `SELECT LTRIM(CONCAT(Firstname,' ',Lastname)) AS Fullname FROM Persons` give you the same problem? (note that there are 3 parameters to `CONCAT()` here: `Firstname`, a one-character `string` containing a space, and `Lastname`; this function takes as many arguments as you throw at it and outputs them as a string)